# How do You Create Frame Like Behavior Without Using Frame Tag?

Tags: html

I want to inject HTML (for advertisement) to every http request to my server. I want the advertisement to be on top of the web page.

The only problem is sometimes in the original website, there is a 'div' with a fixed position, making it overlap with the advertisement.

Example:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

<!-- INJECTED ADVERTISEMENT -->
<div style="position: fixed; top: 0;">
...
</div>
<!-- END OF INJECTED ADVERTISEMENT -->


<!-- ORIGINAL WEBSITE -->
...    
<div style="position: fixed; top: 0;">
...
</div>    
...
<!-- END OF ORIGINAL WEBSITE -->

</body>
</html
```

If I use frame, then the problem will be easily solved. The 'div' with fixed position will not be overlapped with the advertisement, but there will be new problem, which is not every website can be contained in a frame, http://google.com for example.

And I want the advertisement's position to be 'fixed' as well, so the advertisement will always be shown.

Is there a good solution to this?

Thanks

Comment: Advertising pages typically don't mind being embedded in a frame. Do you have a specific AD that shows this behavior or are you just trying to fix a non-problem?

Comment: The advertising page can be embedded in a frame. But what I want is to embed the original website into frame

Answer (score 2):

You can add these lines

```
       <html>
       <head></head>
       <body>

       <!-- INJECTED ADVERTISEMENT -->
       <div style="position: fixed; top: 0; z-index:10000;">
       ...
       </div>
       <!-- END OF INJECTED ADVERTISEMENT -->


       <!-- ORIGINAL WEBSITE -->
        ...    
       <div style="position: fixed; top: 0; z-index:-10;">
        ...
       </div>    
        ...
        <!-- END OF ORIGINAL WEBSITE -->

        </body>
        </html>
```

This will do the work

Comment: What is the reasoning behind the extreme z-indexes?

Comment: Why not just swap the elements instead of using z-indexes?

Comment: Nothing behind it just to make sure none of the other values overlap it

Comment: If I understand well, he can't change the original website code, he can only inject his ad at the beginning of the page. The extreme z-index on his ad could solve the issue even though it's not really clean.

Comment: Using the z-index will only make the advertisement cover the original website and I don't want that to happen.